# How To: Invert Range (Exponential Decay)?

Tags: c#, math

I came across a scenario lately where I needed to scale a value to size based on the distance between two objects (camera and target). The [original issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642903/value-slimming) was that the camera would jump too far from position `x` to position `y` while moving towards the `target`:

> I have that part down, but I'm having an issue with the value being too jumpy as I get closer to the object I am viewing.

The original idea was to scale the zoom distance based on how close the camera was to the target; this was to prevent the camera from ever passing through the target's mesh (or vertices in DirectX 11). Though more traditional systems utilize a collider system to prevent this, this is not a traditional system and can not be coded as such. The original scaling code was straight forward:

```
float scale = 10000f;
if (delta < 0)
    while (target.Scale + (delta / scale) < 0)
        scale *= 10;
else
    while (target.Scale + (delta / scale) > 3)
        scale *= 10;

target.Scale += delta / scale;
target.World = Matrix.Scaling(target.Scale) * Matrix.Identity;
```

A few people made some good points as to what to try, but as of today (8/7/2018) the post still has no working answers. Thus, I have abandoned the approach involved and came to a solution that works but in a different manner.

***The New Problem***: A fellow Stack-Overflow [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6221024/dillon-davis) shared the idea that I should attempt the following line of code:

```
Position += new Vector3(-1 * Math.Sign(e.Delta) * Math.Min(10000f, (Position.X - TargetPosition.X) / c, 0, 0));
```

Where `c` is some constant greater than or equal to two. This was a brilliant idea; this simplified the original code and kept the zoom steady (which wasn't the answer to slowing the value down, but was a start).

This introduced the same issue in a different approach; *how do I slow down my camera as it approaches it's target*. Well, as I played around with the values for `c`, I noticed that the larger `c` became, the slower the zoom would be. Then I began to puzzle on what I should use to adjust the value for `c`. The answer should heavily involve the distance between the camera and the target; but the problem here is that the distance between the camera and the target gets smaller as you get closer, and larger as you get further away. Which leads to:

***The New Question***: How do I take a range such as `3 - 1000` and invert it in the simplest manner to become `1000 - 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my search for an answer, I crawled through the inter-webs. I eventually came to a point where I was ready to give up and ended up asking a friend of mine for help. He called me back an hour later talking about [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay). In his explanation he pretty much quoted the Wikipedia page:

> A quantity is subject to exponential decay if it decreases at a rate [proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)) to its current value.

The math behind it was essentially:

```
c = m - ((m - 3) / 1 + Math.Exp(-10 * ((d - 100) / (r - 100))));
```

Where `c` is the constant needed in the question, `m` is the maximum value for the range, `d` is the distance between the camera and the target, and `r` is the radius of the target.

The implementation was very straight-forward at this point; I removed all of the old code and re-wrote the method as such:

```
Vector3 direction = Position - TargetPosition;
float distance = direction.Length();
float radius = 50000000f;

// Prevent the camera from entering the target.
if (distance <= radius * 1.5 && e.Delta > 0)
    return;

// Zooming out is always the same speed.
float speed = 3;
if (e.Delta > 0) {
    float t = (distance - 100) / (radius - 100);
    speed = 1000 - 997 / (1 + (float)Math.Exp(-10 * t)));
}

direction.Normalize();
Vector3 directionCopy = direction;
direction *= -(Math.Sign(e.Delta) * Math.Min(1000f, distance / speed));
Position = Position + direction;
```

I would like to thank all of the other Stack-Overflow users for their assistance, and if anyone feels as though they can solve the original problem, feel free to give it a shot. Also, if you feel as though you have a better solution, feel free to share it!

Comment: This is in-fact not an exponential decay function, but a shifted and scaled version of the **[Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)**. Sigmoid functions do "decay" exponentially, but at *both ends* of the input range (if the input range is large enough). They are typically used for smooth transitions between two extremal values. If it works for you, then fair enough, but it doesn't seem like the most appropriate function form to use here.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thank you for pointing this out, as I read over your link I found that the math behind it is actually the [Logistic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) which is a derivative of the Sigmoid. I will update the post to reflect this when I have the time to do so.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Also, if you feel you have a better approach *"it doesn't seem like the most appropriate function"*; feel free to post an answer for future readers. Who knows, I may even swap my code to utilize it instead.

Comment: Apologies, wrong link - [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) is the correct one. On second thought this function is indeed very appropriate for this purpose - I failed to note that you were setting the *speed* (not the distance).

Comment: However - if you plot the function `1000 - 997 / (1 + Math.Exp(-10 * t)`, you see that it *increases* as you zoom in. Perhaps you meant something like `997 / (1 + Math.Exp (-10 * (t - offset))) + 3`? Here the `offset` serves to move the curve away from the vertical axis, so that the curve decays as the distance decreases. You may also need to change the "scaling coefficient" `-10`, because this currently causes the curve to decay too slowly.